# How to compile the same CocoaPod with different options based on target?

Tags: ios, cocoapods, networkextension

I have two targets, a Network Extension and its associated app.

They both consume the same CocoaPod, but the CocoaPod needs to be compiled slightly differently for each target.  My understanding is that CocoaPods will only install one version of a specific CocoaPod, so I can't specify different local names for the pods.  This is the basic structure of the Podfile:

```
def common_target_pods
    pod 'MySharedPod'
end

target 'TheApplication' do
    common_target_pods
end

target 'TheNetworkExtension' do    
    common_target_pods
end
```

I've seen how to set per-configuration settings with

```
post_install do |installer_representation|
    installer_representation.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
        target.build_configurations.each do |config|
            config.build_settings['SOME_PARAM'] = 'SOME_VALUE'
        end
    end
end
```

But this still only generates one version of the static library, and I need two.  It's not debug/release that I need to differentiate but code execution in different environments for the same configuration.